# Using a int value, which is in another class file?

Tags: java, class, integer, int

I want to use a int value, that is in Gui.class, in DrawPanel1.class, how can I pass over the int value easily from Class to Class file?
My int value:

`/* Gui.java */
static int gamestate = 1;`

I want to decrease gamestate by 1, in the DrawPanel.java, in a buttonHandler, like so:

```
/*DrawPanel.java */ 
    class StartNewGameHandler implements ActionListener{
     public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
                    gamestate--;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to access a static variable directly, you could use:

```
Gui.gamestate--;
```

However, I'd urge you to keep variables private (other than constants), and access them via properties. Mutable static variables are often a bad idea too.

Comment: Well, I had no choice. If I didnt make it static it gave me an error which made the program unrunnable. It's because i'm using them in main().

Comment: In addition to my answer, I also share the same recommendation.

Comment: @Stan you could create a new object of Gui type and the access the property

Comment: @Stan: The best answer isn't always the one which just shuts the compiler up quickest. You should think about *why* the compiler is complaining, and consider the best way of solving it... which I suggest in this case probably *isn't* just making the variable static.

Comment: @Yet Another Geek: When I do that, it starts up a new JFrame, because the calling of JFrame is in Gui.java.

Comment: @Stan: So maybe Gui isn't the right place for the variable in the first place. You may well want to change the *presentation* of your game state from the *model* of it.

Answer (score 0):

If Gui and DrawPanel are in the same package you could use

`Gui.gamestate--`

else you have to declare gamestate as public
and then call

`Gui.gamestate--`

Answer (score 0):

You just make it `public` like:

```
public static int gamestate = 1;
```

and then you call it staticly:

```
Gui.gamestate
```

Comment: I'm getting an error.                                      `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself
 at java.awt.Container.checkAddToSelf(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at collide.DrawPanel1.<init>(DrawPanel1.java:50)
 at collide.Gui.<init>(Gui.java:27)
 at collide.Gui.main(Gui.java:56)`

Comment: @Stan it seems that this error is independent of the other one, but the compiler just picked it up now, as the other one was fixed

Answer (score 0):

The standard OOP way to pass data between classes is using getters/setters:

```
class Gui {
    private int gameState;

    public void setGameState(int gameState) {
        this.gameState = gameState;
    }
}
```

Of course, you can use a static variable, but this is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: Well, this is my main(): `  public static void main(String[] args){
   Gui game = new Gui();
   //STARTING MENU
   if(gamestate == 1){ 
    game.startgo();
   } 
   //THE ACTUAL GAME
   if(gamestate == 0){
    game.go();
   }
  } ` and, if I make the gameState int non-static, it will give me this error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field gameState

Comment: Yes, but why do you have to necessarily access it from a static method?

Comment: Well, not necessarily, but, I decided to start this all over, I messed up alot of code.